# Most elegant to calculate many columns in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given a numpy matrix, I'm looking to create a new matrix composed of columns calculated from columns of the starting matrix. I can do this with vector operations but it's not very elegant. As an example, say I want to calculate simple growth rates.

Starting matrix:

```
m = np.matrix(np.random.random_integers(1,100, size=(5,3)))
matrix([[ 96,  61, 100],
       [ 18,  82,  17],
       [ 59,  35,  58],
       [ 26,  97,  95],
       [ 25,  49,  32]])
```

Desired calculated matrix g:

```
g0 = np.empty((5, 1))
g0[:] = np.nan
g1 = (m[:, 1] - m[:, 0]) / m[:, 0]
g2 = (m[:, 2] - m[:, 1]) / m[:, 1]
g = np.hstack((g0, g1, g2))
matrix([[        nan, -0.36458333,  0.63934426],
        [        nan,  3.55555556, -0.79268293],
        [        nan, -0.40677966,  0.65714286],
        [        nan,  2.73076923, -0.02061856],
        [        nan,  0.96      , -0.34693878]])
```

The real m matrix I'm dealing with contains many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular problem, you can do the calculations in one step:

```
>>> (m[:,1:]- m[:,:-1])/m[:,:-1]
array([[-0.36458333,  0.63934426],
       [ 3.55555556, -0.79268293],
       [-0.40677966,  0.65714286],
       [ 2.73076923, -0.02061856],
       [ 0.96      , -0.34693878]])
```

or

```
>>> np.diff(m,1) / m[:,:-1]
array([[-0.36458333,  0.63934426],
       [ 3.55555556, -0.79268293],
       [-0.40677966,  0.65714286],
       [ 2.73076923, -0.02061856],
       [ 0.96      , -0.34693878]])
```

and then you can add a column of nans if you insist.  (Aside: note that I'm using arrays instead of matrices, because they're usually more convenient, but the above will work with matrices as well.)

Even if the operation can't be so easily vectorized -- say that there were dependencies between the column calculations -- as long as the number of columns is small compared to the number of rows you might as well do the loop manually.  Looping over the smallest dimension(s) and vectorizing the calculation over the remaining ones is a common compromise.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!